# Google Tasks-like js control

Tags: javascript

I need to imitate [Google Tasks](https://mail.google.com/tasks/ig?pli=1) look and feel with a few minor changes.

Is there an open-source JavaScript control that I may reuse?

The main feature that I look for is "plain-text-like" feel of the in-place task editing process.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Google's coolness is built using their Web Toolkit (GWT). See the following url for a gallery of their widgets, which you may see throughout many of their sites (e.g., stackpanel for tasks): http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html

Unfortunately (for me), most of the code is Java, which is then compiled into highly optimized Javascript. For more info. on Google's Web Toolkit, check out http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid using GWT. Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Did some looking around and found the following Ajax-MySQL TODO list w/ downloadable source: http://www.hesswebservices.com/download_scripts/TodoV1/

You can always hack the CSS and JS code until it works for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for a regular editable list with checkboxes. I need to imitate Google Tasks look and feel. :-)